# dse enterprise solr re-indexing

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Is there a way to re-index a solr core without impacting applications that rely on that core? For example, can we spin up a new replacement core and let it get indexed fully before swapping out and decommissioning the old core?

In our use case, we cannot afford to have partial data available to our applications - which is what will happen if we do an in-place re-index. Currently, it takes anywhere between 24 - 36 hours to fully re-index our core.

Comment: Have you tried [CoreAdmin's SWAP](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP) ? Or if you're running a cluster, the `CREATEALIAS` option for collections? (i.e. alias your existing collection, point your clients to the alias, then make the alias point to the new collection when it's ready)

Comment: @MatsLindh - thanks for the suggestion, but given that this is the solr integrated with dse - I don't believe it supports the Swap or createalias options (I could be wrong, but could not find anything in the doc)

Comment: @CalebRackliffe - thanks for the suggestion - this is exactly what I was looking for - wasn't sure if dse search handled rolling re-indexes. If you elevate your comment to an answer, I can mark it as the correct answer so that others can reference it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relevant keyspace is configured with a replication factor of 2 or more, you should be able to do a rolling re-index of your cluster without affecting availability. (i.e. You should be able to use `dsetool reload_core <your core name> distributed=false reindex=true`.) While a node is re-indexing, it will not service queries for the token ranges it owns, unless there are no other replicas available.